# What is yield doing in this situation?

Tags: ruby, block

I am reading [Programming Ruby 1.9 (3rd edition): The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9), and have a question about one of the code examples.

On page 101, there is this example:

```
class VowelFinder
    include Enumerable
    def initialize(string)
        @string = string
    end
    def each
        @string.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |vowel|
            yield vowel
        end
    end
end

vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped")
vf.inject(:+)   # =>    "euiooue"
```

In the `each` method, each matching result from `scan` is passed to the block, where `yield` is called. But what exactly is the `yield vowel` line doing? From what I understand, `yield` is used to call a block (that was passed to a method) from within a method. What is it doing in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's calling the block that's passed to the method, just as you understand.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that this is a classical usage of a `Enumerable` mix-in + `each` (which must yield the desired elements). You just need to implement `each` and you get all the cool methods (in your example, `inject`) of enumerables. See:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html

*"The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of the collection."*